# What Optimization Algorithm to use to Find Site Locations?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, gis, simulated-annealing

I need to find an algorithm which will pick 6 zip codes from a list of 956 (the six zip codes will later be used as sales territory centers). I'm happy that I have a good function to rank possible solutions. I also know which zip codes are adjacent to each other.

My first thought was to try simulated annealing. This gave inconsistent, and really not great results. The image below shows six territory centers which are attempting to maximize the coverage of total population (see below).[image: Population Coverage from Six Locations]

Comment: Sounds like a [Metric k-center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_k-center) problem. An exact solution is NP-hard, but there exist approximation algorithms.

Comment: Well... tune the parameters of your simulated-annealing approach. It's one  of not to many algorithms which have some strong theoretical results. These might not be enough for your case, but not playing around with these is wasted work. Using only your rating-function this can be tackled by black-box optimization, but this kind of learning is very hard. It migh be better to incorporate your function into some algorithm if it's possible (e.g. allowing to compute gradients and co. != black-box). Zhuoran's idea assumes a lot about your rating-function, but it's a good recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm currently taking a few approaches. I will try to tune the simulated-annealing algorithm. I'm also attempting to implement an Ant-Colony algorithm as well as a gradient descent approach.